# $\Vert A\Vert_{op}=\Vert PAP^{-1}\Vert_{op}$ for $P$ orthogonal

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthogonality

Let $A,P\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $P$ is orthogonal, i.e. $ PP^t=Id$.

prove that $\Vert A\Vert_{op}=\Vert PAP^{-1}\Vert_{op}$.

I am working with this definition: $\Vert M\Vert_{op}=sup\{\Vert Mx\Vert\ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}^n \text{ and } \Vert x\Vert=1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$||PAP^{-1}x||^2=\langle PAP^{-1}x, PAP^{-1}x\rangle=\langle AP^{-1}x,AP^{-1}x\rangle$$

Now $$||PAP^{-1}||_{op}=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n,||x||=1}\{||PAP^{-1}x||\}=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n,||x||=1}\{||AP^{-1}x||\}=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n,||x||=1}\{||AP^{-1}(Px)||\}=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n,||x||=1}\{||Ax||\}=||A||_{op}
$$
(This is because $P$ is an orthogonal matrix)

Comment: Why is the third equality in the second row true?

Comment: Because $P$ is orthogonal, $P$ is onto. So as you go on varying $x$, $Px$ covers the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: But is she an endomorphism on the sphere i.e. covers the sphere with vectors from it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: It is true that $P$ is onto $\mathbb{R}^n$. But is $P:S^1\to S^1$ onto? because unless maybe the vector that you choose by replacing $x$ with $Py$ is not of norm $\Vert y\Vert= 1$???

Comment: Well $||px||^2=\langle Px, Px \rangle=\langle x, x \rangle=||x||^2$

Comment: Oh right, thank you for the explanation.